# Optimization problem, how to obtain the optimal F?

Tags: optimization

The objective is as follows:

$\min_{\mathbf{F}} a Tr(\mathbf{F} \mathbf{F}^H) - \mathbf{b}\mathbf{F}^H \mathbf{C} \mathbf{F} \mathbf{d}$

$s.t.\ \ \ Tr(\mathbf{F} \mathbf{F}^H)<p$

where $a$ and $p$ are scalars, $\mathbf{b}$ is $1 \times N$ real vector,  $\mathbf{d}$ is $N\times 1$ real vector, $\mathbf{C}$ is  $N \times N$ Hermitian transpose matrix, $\mathbf{F}$ is  $N \times N$.

It is obvious that if all the variables are scalars, the optimal $F^\ast$ is either $0$ or $p$. So how about the matrix case?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any constraints on $F$? Otherwise, you can choose $F$ such that your objective function goes to $-\infty$.